# REACT NATIVE FIRESTORE SUBCOLLECTION PROBLEM

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve a firestore firebase subcollection.

With this code below everything is ok:

```
  await firestore()
    .collection('VILLES')
    .doc('9HNkAv99pd1rm9Q3vdwd')
    .collection('restaurents')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const {image, address, description, title, ratings, contact} =
          doc.data();

        list.push({
          id: doc.id,
          image: image,
          address: address,
          description: description,
          title: title,
          ratings: ratings,
          contact: contact,
        });
      });
    });
  setrestaurents(list);
  if (loading) {
    setloading(false);
  }
  console.log('restaurents:', restaurents);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

But the problem is I have many documents which have a personal collection
how can I write a code so that every document will retrieve his own subcollection, and I know the problem is around the document Id

I tried this

```
  await firestore()
    .collection('VILLES')
    .doc(VILLESId)
    .collection('restaurents')
    .get()
```

but I'm getting this error

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref2.VILLESId')

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all documents from all `restaurents` subcollections, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) like this:

```
  firestore()
    .collectionGroup('restaurents')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        ...
```

This will take all documents from all `restaurents` collections.

---

If you need to know the `VILLE` document ID for a specific `restaurent` document in the above, you can get it with:

```
doc.ref.parent().parent().id
```

Comment: IT IS NOT WHAT IM LOOKING FOR I HAVE A COLLECTION NAME TOWN AND THIS COLLECTION HAVE DOCCUMENTS LETS SAY WE  HAVE 5 DOCUMENTS AND EVERY DOCUMENT HAVE A SUBCOLLECTION THE PROBLEM IS THAT WHEN I SELECT A SPECIFIC DOCUMENT  I WILL LIKE  TO RETREAVE THE SUBCOLLECTION BELONG TO THIS DOCUMENT IF I CAME BACK AND SELECT ANOTHER DOUMENT I WILL  LIKE  TO RETREAVE HIS OWN SUBCOLLECTION .TO TEST MY CODE I COPY ONE DOCUMENT ID AND PASS IT IT WORK FINE BUT IF I USE THIS CODE I CANT GET THE REST DOCUMENT OF THE FIRST COLLECTION      THANKS FOR ANY HELP

Comment: Please don't type in all-caps, as that reduces readability and is commonly perceived as yelling.

Comment: i'm very sorry i didn't know that.excuse me

Comment: @GroupeAkoua please see [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456701/how-to-read-a-sub-collections-document-fields-from-firestore-in-react-native) where this question was answered.